# VPN / VPS and IP logs

Tags: vpn, logging, ipsec, web-hosting, l2tp

Here's the situation:

1) I rent a VPS at a hoster and install VPN on it.

2) Completely disable all logs. Those logs that can not be disabled - permanently delete.

3) I connect to my VPS via VPN (L2TP/IPSec) from my machine and go to some website. 
The owners of this site will want to identify me. They define the IP and go to the server hosting company to get the data (let assume they will have order) .

There is no any logs on the server. But probably in the data center will log all who are connected to this server. Correspondingly, there can be seen IP’s who did connections to this server.
Is it possible?

And if the answer is yes, are there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no control over what the VPS is logging. They may be logging all communications, or none. There's no way for you to control it and no way for you to know what they are doing. The VPS provider is subject to all laws for its locale including search warrants.

If you are looking for anonymity, consider Tor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any way to hide IP from the VPS-hosting using a VPN? (In my case I can't use Tor. Here I explain why: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/125024/do-i-have-a-ip-leak-if-i-use-tor-and-skype-udp/125026)

Comment: Any VPN is going to be a two way connection.  They need to know the way back, which of course might be a proxy.   You can anonymously send UDP packets outside a VPN though by spoofing the source address.   A solution of limited usefulness, being unguaranteed and one-way and all.  (maybe 'any' is too strong a word)

Comment: @ideloxew using a VPN will make your connection to the VPS trace back to the VPN provider. If they log, then a motivated investigator could piece the VPS and VPN logs together, but it is more complex. Using providers in different, law enforcement unfriendly countries will increase complexity.